# Why is this cronjob not working?

Tags: cron, ruby, crontab, cronjob

I have a ruby script in `~/custom_scripts/get_all_products.rb`.

I want it to run every night at 04:00.

Here's what the cronjob in `crontab -e` looks like:

```
MAILTO="<email>"
0 4 * * * ruby ~/custom_scripts/get_all_products.rb
```

But it's not executing.

What should I try next?

Comment: Do you have the email address filled out in the working version? If so are your getting any emails?  To debug cron I typically open a file to append and write mini log entries from within the script.  I begone with just a started and ended entry and go from there.  You can either remove the lines after you figure out your roadblock, or more likely comment them out in case I ever need them again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had issues with using tilde expansion in crontabs in the past (this may have been on a Unix flavor other than Linux). Still, I'd suggest using `$HOME` instead of `~`.

Also, it's best to specify a full path to your `ruby` executable. The `PATH` used by cron is often not the one you have set in your interactive environment (e.g., on my system, the cron `PATH` is just `/usr/bin:/bin`).

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be two issues you need to solve:

1. ~ is a Shell-synonym for `$HOME`. You should use that in something like cron
2. `$HOME` is might not set correct for your command. `crontab -e` by default is editing root's crontab. Not one of your users. Replace just ~ and `$HOME` with absolute path.

Comment: You are might looking for `crontab -e -u <user>` to define user's crontab.

Comment: Are there any additional pathes set for you rb-stuff? remember, you don't have a login shell here.

Comment: Not that I know of, how do I check?

Comment: Why do you run this stuff as root? WTH? However, check with `set`

Comment: Because I want to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16997/discussion-between-narzero-and-frlan).

Comment: The bourne shell, used by cron, does not support tilde. You need to use $HOME.