# Error 500 with cron job, but no problems in CLI

Tags: ubuntu, cron, curl, ddns

I have a ubuntu 18.04 server running which unfortunately has a dynamic IP. I have set up a free DDNS for it via [duckdns](https://www.duckdns.org/) and followed the [instructions](https://www.duckdns.org/install.jsp) to have my ip updated once in a while with cron. However when running duck.sh manually from the CLI I always get an OK output, and yet when cron runs the file I almost always see the following:

```
<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Very often, this is a path problem.  Capture the `stderr` of your `duck.sh` and edit your post to include it. Is [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/808555/why-is-this-cronjob-not-working) a duplicate of your question?

Comment: @JimL. How do I capture the stderr? No, I'm sure the cron job is being called, because I see the output file of the script

Comment: The cron job is being called, but it's having errors.  I'm not familiar with Ubuntu cron but FreeBSD cron emails the `stderr` (if any) to the owner of the job, or the default `MAILTO` recipient if run from `/etc/crontab`. If you could see those error messages, it may provide clues to what the problems are.  Those errors may very well be an insufficient `PATH` in your script.  A workaround is to forsake `PATH` and put explicit paths on all executables you call in the script.

Comment: @Jim L. So the cron job should be writing to /dev/null, but the file seems to be empty (*/5 * * * * ~/duckdns/duck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)

Comment: Try that as `/full/path/to/duckdns/duck.sh >/tmp/duck.sh.out 2>&1`.  The command example you show discards both `stdout` and `stderr`.